# Opening a URL with POST Parameters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm searching or a way to open a URL with two POST parameters. My only option now is writing a small exe which creates a form in a WebBrowser control then auto-clicks a button, which is horrible. Is there a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working so you can open a standard .html file with a query string to forward the parameters to a URL.

```
function postFromQueryString(url) {
    // grab params from query string into KVP array
    var postParams = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        postParams.push(hash[0]);
        postParams[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    if(postParams.length === 0) {
        alert('No parameter was passed');
        window.close();
        return;
    }
    // create a form
    var formToPost = document.createElement("form");
    formToPost.method="post";
    formToPost.action = url;
    // add params to form
    for (var k in postParams) {
        var postInput = document.createElement("input");
        postInput.setAttribute("name", k);
        postInput.setAttribute("value", postParams[k]);
        formToPost.appendChild(postInput);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(formToPost);
    formToPost.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(formToPost);
}
```

To call it onLoad:

```
(function () {
    // build dynamic form and post
    postFromQueryString('http://yourUrlToPostTo.aspx');
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an HTML File with the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- The function below does a post without requiring a form or the click of a button -->
function postwith (to,p) {
    var myForm = document.createElement("form");
    myForm.method="post" ;
    myForm.action = to ;
    for (var k in p) {
        var myInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        myInput.setAttribute("name", k) ;
        myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
        myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
    myForm.submit() ;
    document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}
</script>
```

Example Usage:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function delconfirm(id){
        if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
        {
            postwith('http://somesite.com/webpagetorecievepost.php',{KEY:VALUE,KEY:'STRING VALUE'});
        }
    }
   </script>
```

You can have as many **KEY:VALUE** pairs as you like.

Once you have this html file you can modify and open it in internet explorer.

Comment: This I'm hopeful for. Doesn't quite do the full process but I'll investigate more tomorrow.

Comment: I'm curious about what you're trying to do. Can you spare some more details?

Answer (score 0):

There are web browser automation tools that can drive IE, for instance [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). Selenium is scriptable, and has drivers for the major browsers. I've only used selenium for this kind of thing, driven by java code; there are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426190/selenium-alternatives).

There are also Windows GUI automation tools, for instance [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), that can open a given program and manipulate GUI elements.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I don't believe I can use cURL to launch iexplore with parameters.

Comment: ah. sorry misunderstood the question